# Difference between geometric simplicial complex and abstract simplicial complex

Tags: general-topology, complex-geometry, geometric-topology, simplex

I don't quite understand the difference between geometric simplicial complex and abstract simplicial complex. Both of their definition and the way you describe them sound almost the same to me.

For example, if there is a set $P = \{a, b, c\}$ then there can be a geometric complex $G = \{a, b, c, \{a, b\}, \{b, c\}, \{c, a\}, \{a, b, c\}\}$, right?

But I guess the abstract complex $A$ is also $\{a, b, c, \{a, b\}, \{b, c\}, \{c, a\}, \{a, b, c\}\}$, which is expressed in the same with $G$.

I was also advised that it doesn't need to have edges. Then how should I understand a simplex such as $<a, b>$?

Comment: No!  The (abstract) simplicial complex $\Delta$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}_f(S)$, some set $S$, satisfying closure under taking subset.  The geometric realisation $\lvert\Delta\rvert$ of the simplicial complex $\Delta$ is the topological space you get from "filling in" the faces in $[0,1]^S$.

Comment: @user10354138 I kinda get it, but exactly. Then how would you describe <a, b> in an abstract complex? Apparently we cannot draw a line like in the geometric complex

Comment: There is no such thing as the ordered pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ in the (abstract) simplicial complex.  An example of a simplicial complex on $\{1,2,3\}$ is $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$, and the geometric realisation of this complex is something that looks like a "V".

Comment: @user10354138 Ok, I got it that there is no order pair. But still, how would you describe {1, 2} without geometric realization? I don't know how I should understand/picture something like {1, 2} or {1, 2, 3} in abstract complex.

Comment: This is just a 2-element subset, just like any other 2-element sets such as $\{\{\text{John}\},\{\text{Smith}\}\}$.

Comment: @user10354138 Okay... then there is nothing connecting those 2 vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply these have different definitions. I'm not sure why you call your $G$ a geometric simplicial complex, it is not.

A pair $(X,S)$ is called an **abstract simplicial complex**, if $X$ is a (nonempty) set and $S$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that if $P\in S$ and $A\subseteq P$ then $A\in S$ *and* all singletons belong to $S$. I will call elements of $S$ abstract simplicies (even though I don't think this is a standard nomenclature). Note that this is an abstract approach, we don't have edges, faces, etc. Although we can imagine that if say $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $S=\big\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\big\}$ then $\{1,2\}$ is an "edge" connecting vertex $1$ to $2$, while $\{1,2,3\}$ is a "triangle" on $3$ vertices. This observation is actually a basis for geometric realization (more on that later).

**(Geometric) simplicial complex** on the other hand is a pair $(X,S)$ where $X$ is a *topological* space and $S$ is a collection of continuous functions $f:\Delta^n\to X$ (where $\Delta^n$ denotes [the $n$-simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex), i.e. $n$ dimensional triangle) such that:

1. $f$ restricted to the interior of $\Delta^n$ is injective
2. Restriction of $f$ to one of the faces of $\Delta^n$ belongs to $S$ as well. Here a face of $\Delta^n$ is naturally identified with $\Delta^{n-1}$.
3. A subset $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for all $f\in S$.

This definition comes from Allen Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*. Note that $n$ is not constant here, it varies, in fact condition 2. says that if $f:\Delta^n\to X$ belongs to $S$ then we have some maps $\Delta^m\to X$ for any $0\leq m<n$ in $S$ as well.

$S$ is often called a simplicial structure on $X$. Here we already have edges, faces, etc.

In other words geometric simplicial complex is a concrete topological space divided into subspaces, each homeomorphic to a triangle (have a look at a very closely related concept of [triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology))). For example a triangle on the plane, or two triangles on the plane glued at a single vertex. Or boundary of a triangle. But things that are not triangles are also simplicial complexes, for example a sphere or a real line. Many topological spaces you'll encounter actually have simplicial structure, but not all of them, e.g. rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ (or any other non-locally connected space).

So what about geometric realization? There is a way of constructing a geometric simplicial complex from an abstract simplicial complex $K$ in a "nice way" (meaning abstract simplex $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ corresponds to triangle on $n$ vertices, i.e. $n-1$ dimensional triangle). This is called [the geometric realization of $K$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex#Geometric_realization). Roughly speaking for any abstract simplex $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ we just take an $n-1$-dimensional triangle, and then we glue those triangles at common faces (prescribed in the abstract definition). Of course except for the dimension $0$ which has no faces.

---

Here are few examples of a geometric realization of some **abstract** simplicial complex:

**Example 1.** Let $X=\{1\}$ and $S=\big\{\{1\}\big\}$. Then the geometric realization of $(X, S)$ is a $0$-dimensional triangle, i.e. a discrete single point.

**Example 2.** Let $X=\{1,2\}$ and $S=\big\{\{1\},\{2\}\big\}$. Then we have two $0$-dimensional triangles, so the resulting geometric realization is a discrete space on two points.

**Example 3.** Let $X=\{1,2\}$ and $S=\big\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\big\}$. This is more interesting. We have two $0$-dimensional triangles, and one $1$-dimensional triangle: an interval. We glue that $1$-dimensional triangle to $0$-dimensional triangles on faces (vertices in that case). The resulting space is homeomorphic to a closed interval.

**Example 4.** Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ with $S=\big\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}\big\}$. Then we take three $0$-dimensional simplices (points) for each $\{x\}$, three $1$-dimensional simplices (closed intervals) for each $\{a,b\}$ and glue them at vertices. This produces a triangle without interior.

**Example 5.** Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ with $S=\big\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\big\}$. This is similar to example 1, except we have additional $\{1,2,3\}$ abstract simplex. So we have one additional step: we generate a $2$-dimensional triangle and glue its faces with what we've already constructed in example 1. This gives as a triangle together with its interior.

**Example 6.** Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with $S=\big\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{1,4\}\big\}$. Similarly to example 2 we have a full triangle, but additionaly vertex $\{4\}$ outside, which is glued to vertex $\{1\}$ via $1$-dimensional triangle: a straight line. So it is a full triangle together with a line segment going out of one of the vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to check some basic things first. You mentioned that G in my question is not a geometric simplicial complex. But the definition of a geometric simplicial complex I taught is, "A geometric simplicial complex K in R^n is a set of simplices of various demensions that satisfies the following two restrictions. (a) every face of every simplex already in it, and for (b) any of its 2 simplices, their intersection is either empty or a face of both."

Comment: If the example of G I made is not correct, could you give me any example of G using the vetices set P={a, b, c} ?

Comment: @Lucy I think the concept of *geometric simplicial complex* is not really standardized in  the literature. Some authors define it as a collection of geometric simplices in a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^N$ such that the intersection of two simplices is either empty of a face of both. Here a  geometric simplex is the convex hull of finitely many points of $\mathbb R^N$ in general position. This is the definition you have in mind.

Comment: And, by the way, you should use mathjax. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation .

Comment: @Lucy indeed, as Paul Frost said, there is no standard definition of geometric simplicial complex. However your definition is a special case of my definition. But even under your definition your $G$ is not a geometric simplicial complex. Where do you have simplexes in your $G$? [Simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) is a triangle, the convex hull of finitely many vectors (under specific linear independence condition). It is not a finite set (unless we deal with $0$-dimensional simplicial complex). Your $G$ is literally an abstract simplicial complex, not geometric.

Comment: @Lucy here's an example of a geometric simplicial complex: $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ 0\leq x\leq 1;\ 0\leq y\leq 1;\ y\leq x\}$. A triangle on the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Also I already gave you 6 examples in my answer.

Comment: @freakish I didn't know that those S in the examples were geometric complex... But I don't see big difference between your S, and my G ((P={a, b, c} with G = {,,,{,},{,},{,},{,,}}) I think the only difference is that I didn't include '{ }' for a, b, c. So, if I write G = {{a}, {b}, {c}, {a, b}, {b, c}, {c, a}, {a, b, c}}, is it a geometric simplicial complex now?

Comment: @Lucy in my answer, in examples, $(X,S)$ are **abstract** simplicial complexes. Examples are about geometric realization of an abstract simplicial complex, i.e. how to turn an abstract complex into geometric. There is no "geometric realization of geometric complex", that is meaningless, and should be clear from the context. But I've updated the answer, just in case. Also I already gave you an explicit example of a **geometric** simplicial complex in my previous comment. Geometric simplicial complexes are (at least under your definition) infinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ composed of triangles.